# About the phrase "combinatorial characterization"

Tags: terminology

What does the phrase ***"combinatorial characterization"*** mean? Does it mean ***"discrete"***, regardless of topological concepts? I don't know, I would appreciate your kind answer. For example, a subshift is a subset $X\subset A^G$ closed and invariant, but the subshifts have a combinatorial characterization: equivalently we found a finite set of patterns $\mathcal{F}$ such that  $$X=\{x\in A^G: P\sqsubset x \Rightarrow P\notin \mathcal{F}\}.$$

What other uses do you know for this phrase?

Comment: It would be clearer if you gave context; where did you see this? Can you quote an excerpt?

Comment: Do you mean [combinatorial proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_proof) ?

Comment: Any connection to Sperner's theorem ?

Comment: What are $A$ and $G$ in notation $A^G$ ?

Comment: $A$ is a set with the discrete topology, $G$ is a group and $A^G$ represents the set of maps of the form $G\to A$ with the product topology.